# Error al intentar hacer un formato PDF

Tags: php, html, fpdf

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un formato PDF para mi sistema web pero voy empezando y me manda un error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebapdf\reporte.php on line 23

Este es mi código de un archivo

```
function Footer(){ 

    $this->SetY(-15);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    $this->Cell(0,10, 'Pagina ' $this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C' ); 
}
```

Y este es mi código de otro archivo:

```
<?php 

    include 'reporte.php';
    require 'conexion.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM mvs";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);


    $pdf = new REPORTE(); // Recibe parametros para el tamaño de la hoja (se pueden meter arreglos)
    $pdf->AliasPages(); //Esta linea sirve para poner en funcionamiento la variable nb
    $pdf->Addpage();

    $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12); //Asigna valores para el contenido 

    $pdf->Cell(70,6,'MVS',1,0,'C',1); //Crea celdas decontenido
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,'ID',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,'VALOR',1,0,'C',1);

    $pdf->output(); 
?>
```

Pero no logro encontrar mi error ... ¿Podrían ayudarme?

Comment: Te falta concatenar la cadena 

'Pagina '        **.**      $this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C' ); // el **.**  que está

Comment: Ya pude hacerlo ... aun asi muchas gracias por la ayuda... Efectivamente era eso